# When creating a custom sObject, what metadata is created is typically generated

Tags: custom-object

Typically when creating a new custom sObject I prefer to do so in the my sandbox so that I don't have to create the object, fields, tabs, etc. twice. With that said I've noticed in the past that when I create the object there are multiple pieces of data generated, for example:

- **objects/Custom__c.object** *(This includes object details like:)*

  - Fields
  - RecordTypes
- **sharingRules/Correlation__c.sharingRules**
- **tabs/Correlation__c.tab**

I want to know if there is a checklist of sorts somewhere that would describe everything related to a new custom sObject so that it doesn't get missed in a workflow like this.